# Rails + Dalli memcache gem: DalliError: No server available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, dalli

Hi I'm having trouble setting up my Rails project on my server because apache keeps complaining

`DalliError: No server available`.

I installed `memcached` on my ubuntu machine, but it still doesn't work. My rails project also has `config.cache_store = :dalli_store, 'localhost:11211', { :namespace => "production" }` in environments/production.rb. How would I debug this?

My log shows before each request:

```
localhost:11211 failed (count: 6)
DalliError: No server available
```

telnet to 11211:

```
    root@s2:/usr/local/www/production/current/log# telnet localhost 11211
    Trying 127.0.1.1...
    telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Comment: What are you running to start memcached?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I had the same problem. 
First I installed memcached as a gem 
`gem install memcached`
and got the error "DalliError: No server available"

Then I installed memcached by doing 
`sudo apt-get install memcached`.
It works fine now.

Comment: Make sure the service is also enabled. `sudo systemctl enable memcached` (start on boot) `sudo systemctl start memcached` (start now) If you are unsure if the service is running use `systemctl status memcached`

Answer (score 15):

If you're a Homebrew user:

```
brew install memcached
```

Check if the service is running:

```
brew services list
```

If not, start it:

```
brew services start memcached
```

Answer (score 3):

It was because someone changed the `/etc/hosts` file to point `127.0.1.1` to localhost instead of `127.0.0.1`. After changing that, `memcached` worked.

Answer (score 3):

Use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` should solve your (and mine) issue.

`config.cache_store = :dalli_store, '127.0.0.1:11211', { namespace: 'production' }`

Comment: Had the same issue. This happens if Ruby interprets "localhost" as "::1" (IPv6 address). See: https://github.com/petergoldstein/dalli/issues/130#issuecomment-2531438

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer will probably solve the issue for 95% of people who are seeing this error, but in my case I found the issue to be far more fundamental:

From the server, I was unable to `ping 127.0.0.1`. This meant `Dalli` could not connect to the `memcache` server, which by default runs on `127.0.0.1:11211`.

There are a number of things that *could* cause this issue, but the most likely is simply a missing network interface. If you run `ifconfig`, you *should* see something like this in the output:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:15686 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15686 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:23730314 (23.7 MB)  TX bytes:23730314 (23.7 MB)
```

If this is missing, ensure your `/etc/network/interfaces` file contains the following local interface definition:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

And then restart the networking service:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had recently updated memcached on the server, but the Ruby daemon had kept running through the upgrade.  After simply restarting the Ruby daemon, the errors went away.  (I also restarted mechached.)