# devise current_user found in a session controller, but it became nil when comes to another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using devise for authentication,

I put some text after "super" in SessionsController#create method like below, to find the "current_user" value in the browser(using better_errors gem).

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    super
    error_debug
  end

  def edit
    super
  end
end
```

in routes.rb

```
root :to => "welcome#index"
```

I got the current_user value like expected in SessionsController#create, but current user value is 'nil' when it comes to welcome#index method even after signin.

I can't able to find the reason behind it, please someone assist me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the log file, I found that, the bug is

```
Dall::error server not found
```

Then I installed memcached by doing  `sudo apt-get install memcached`. It works fine now. For more clarification, click the below link

[Rails + Dalli memcache gem: DalliError: No server available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497502/rails-dalli-memcache-gem-dallierror-no-server-available)

Answer (score 0):

First signed in and check in better_error value of current_user

Comment: I am telling after signin. "create" is the login method, hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps:

```
gem install 'devise'
rails generate devise:install
rails generate devise User
rake db:migrate
```

**Your Routes should be like this**
devise_for :users
>
  root :to => "home#index"

Change your development config add following line to config/environments/development.rb
`config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }`

Add this code to your controller
`before_filter :authenticate_user!`

**And if you are using rails 4 so add this code to your application**

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

def configure_permitted_parameters

devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit({ roles: [] }, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }

devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email) }

end
 end

Answer (score 0):

Do you have protect_from_forgery method call in your application controller? Look at this guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html